# How to alert on 90% use of physical RAM

Tags: windows, splunk, perfmon

I am trying to create an alert when 90% of RAM is used.
I have determined that Committed bytes is the amount of RAM in use but I don't know how to get total RAM.
I am NOT trying to find memory but a percentage of physical ram in use.
Perfmon stats have been indexed for me. I am new to SPLUNK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another peformance counter that is often also ingested with pefmon, PercentCommittedBytesInUse . I would suggest using that counter, if available.

Other Perfmon counters you can look for include "Available Mbytes"

Alternatively, you can get the total available memory using WinHostMon, Powershell or System Event logs